# Aggregation Median/Mean Queries

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have an index with a type that can be reduced to:

```
{
  'date': DATE_STRING,
  'owner': INT,
  'color: 'red' | 'purple' | 'blue'
}
```

and am looking to make queries to present the following data, where an owner's value is equal to the aggregate number of items they own that are 'blue' subtracted by the number of item's they own that are 'red' over a requested time (Don't ask why):

- minimum value of any owner (within requested time)
- maximum value of any owner (within requested time)
- mean value of all owners (within requested time)
- median value of all owners (within requested time)
- a particular owner's value (within requested time)

Answer (score 0):

Set up the index:

```
PUT colorful
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "color": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Insert a few docs

```
POST colorful/_doc
{"date":"2020-05-28T19:56:12.237Z","owner":131351351,"color":"red"}

POST colorful/_doc
{"date":"2020-04-28T19:58:02.110Z","owner":35135125,"color":"purple"}

POST colorful/_doc
{"date":"2020-05-15T19:58:15.966Z","owner":997654341,"color":"blue"}

POST colorful/_doc
{"date":"2020-05-21T19:58:35.766Z","owner":366449,"color":"red"}
```

Filter by a date range & aggregate. Min, Max, Avg(=Mean) can be calculated using `stats`, for `median` there's `percentiles[50]`. Not sure what you meant by `a particular owner's value` but the actual range-filtered docs can be fetched using `top_hits` plus you could add a filter for a specific doc.

```
GET colorful/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "now-3M",
        "lte": "now-1h"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "1)general_stats": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "owner"
      }
    },
    "2)median": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "owner",
        "percents": [
          50
        ]
      }
    },
    "3)top_hits": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By 'a particular owner's value' I mean that I want to be able to query all the posts within a given time frame that have a specific owner, and get the calculated value based off the counts of each color.

Comment: still don’t follow. Please provide an example response plus the calculation.